# Search Display controller always returns true with more cells

Tags: ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to use `UISearchDisplayController` to filter out cells in a table view but whichs works just fine when I have less than 7 cells which is up to the iphone screen size. As soon as I try to search through a view controller that has more than 7 cells, the app crashes because `self.searchDisplayController.active` always returns true before I start typing.

Here is a code snippet where my app crashes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    SubRefCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"cell is nill");
        cell = [[SubRefCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
    }

    int row=[indexPath row];

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) { //is always true when more than 7 cells
        NSLog(@"Here is the table of results: %@",self.searchResults);
        cell.subRefLabel.text = self.searchResults[row];
        NSLog(@"failed ");
        cell.subRefDescLabel.text = _Refs.SubRefDesc[row]; //fix later


    } else {
        //set all the cells with the Sub Reference names and their descriptions
        cell.subRefLabel.text = _Refs.SubReference[row];
        cell.subRefDescLabel.text = _Refs.SubRefDesc[row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In other cases were I have less than 7 cells, `self.searchDisplayController.active` will return false until I start typing into the search bar.

Here is the error I am getting:
`* -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds for empty array'*`

Why would searchDisplayController.active be true whenever there are more cells than the iphone screen size can view?

Comment: In each of your TVC data source methods, are you checking whether you are providing information for your primary table view `self.tableView` or your `UISearchDisplayController` table view `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`?